# VBA: Move values below to emptied cell

Tags: excel, vba, cells

I have this sub that clears values in a row:

```
Sub ClearRow_Click()
    Dim currRow As Long
    currRow = ActiveCell.Row

    If currRow >= 5 And currRow <= 300 Then
        Range("A" & currRow).ClearContents
    End If

End Sub
```

Note: currRow is the row that gets cleared.

What I want to do is include a piece of code that would move all following values in column A (length is up until row 300), starting the next row after currRow (currRow + 1) into currRow. So after clearing a row, we have this:

```
Column A
1111

3333
4444
```

Then I want the code to do this after:

```
Column A
1111
3333
4444
```

I've tried `.End(xlDown)` with `Selection.cut` but I get reference errors due to cut, since I have other columns that refer to A, for example in B2 I have:

```
=IF(A2<>"", $B$1, "")
```

And this results to #REF! errors and format changes when I move cells around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit brute-force, but I think it gets what you're after.

Assuming your columns of data are in columns A:J, and that you want to *shift* the values from all rows *beneath* the `ActiveCell`, up one row (effectively replacing the `ActiveRow` with the

```
Option Explicit
Dim rng As Range
Dim shiftRng As Range

Sub ClearRow_Click()
    Dim currRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngShift As Range

    currRow = ActiveCell.Row
    'This is the full range of data
    If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Range("A5:J300")

    'This gets the next n rows to the last row of your range
    If rngShift Is Nothing Then Set rngShift = Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row + 1) & ":J300")

    If currRow >= 5 And currRow <= 300 Then
       '# This copies ONLY column A and moves the values up one row
       '  This will leave intact all of the rest of the data in columns B:J, etc.
       '  This preserves formatting -- essentially it just moves the values
        rngShift.Columns(1).Offset(-1).Value = rngShift.Columns(1).Value
        '# Get rid of the value in the last row, since it's been shifted up
        Range("A300").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have other cells referring to column A. Please my edit. When I tried this, I got  #REF! errors.

Comment: Are these cells only in column B?

Comment: No, in 10+ other columns. I would rather not shift cells because I want to keep the length at 300.

Comment: OK so basically you need to shift the *values* from all rows <= 300, up one row, after you do the `ClearContents`, right?

Comment: Well, not all rows could have values. There could only be 3 rows filled and the rest empty. But I don't want to delete/shift rows. Basically I want something like a the copy function but moves the values instead of copying.

Comment: Right, you want to *move* the values up. All values beneath the `ActiveCell`, should be *moved* up one row, so that value in row 9 goes in to row 8, value in row 10 goes in to row 9, etc.?

Comment: Yes. This avoids format changes and reference errors.

Comment: Do you see how many details you left out of your original question? Like even just now, you mentioned "format changes" which even my revised answer doesn't handle (but it could be modified to do so).

Comment: Sorry about that. The solution worked but I edited the question to make it more understandable for other people. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers and glad to help!  Next time just try to include as much detail as possible in the question, otherwise the answers you receive may not fully address the challenges you're facing.  Good luck! !